# getting direction from latitude and longitude

Tags: java, android, geocoding

I have calculated the distance between two latitude and longitudes using the Haversine formula,but how can I know the direction to which I should move.

**for example : the distance of a hotel is 10 m from my location but i don't know which direction it is.**
Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I haven't misunderstood, you should use the `bearing`. It refers always to `north`

Comment: could you just provide a sample example on how to use bearing as i am a newbee

Comment: It is not a matter of programming, but it is mathematics.

Comment: On searching about bearing i  found that it provides angle between the coordinates.Am I right?